# Variable bound with ngModel not updated when native element is modified

Tags: angular, data-binding, directive, angular-ngmodel

There is an Angular Directive, that should allow only numbers in an `input`.
Its code is following:

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  ChangeDetectorRef,
  Renderer2
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "input[onlyNumbers]"
})
export class OnlyNumbersDirective {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  @HostListener("input", ["$event"]) onInputChange(event) {
    const initValue = this.elementRef.nativeElement.value;
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = initValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, "");
  }
}
```

The `input`, which uses the directive looks following:

```
<input
  type="tel"
  [maxlength]="4"
  [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
  autocomplete="off"
  onlyNumbers
/>
```

The `input` uses the `[(ngModel)]` to have two way data binding to `inputValue`.

If we try to write a letter in the `input` the first letter is accepted. The next letters not anymore.

I guess the `[(ngModel)]` is not able to detect all the changes of the native element. I tried to use `Renderer2` to set the native element value following way:

```
this.renderer.setValue(this.elementRef.nativeElement, initValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, ""));
```

But it did not help.

A `stackblitz` example can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel-question

The question is, why does this happen? Can this problem be solved with using `Renderer2` or should I not go in this direction further?

Comment: Your stackblitz is working

Comment: That's strange, I did it with Chrome. When I write a letter in the `input` the value of `inputValue` will contain one letter. Note, that the `input` is maximum 4 characters long. I suggest to try to write a letter as the first input character.

Comment: I tried it. Also code was changed. It is not like with your last code block in question. Can you open and check again your stackblitz ?

Comment: I just checked the stackblitz and it seems to be fine. I left the commented `renderer` code snippet in the stackblitz example, so if someone wants to check that, it can be uncommented. I did not add the commented code part to the directive code in my question.
There should be no other differences between the stackblitz code and the code blocks in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Make this replace change in inputValue property of component instead of changing dom element.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I drop the directive, and remove the `[(ngModel)]` and change the `inputValue` whenever an `input` event fires, then it is working file. I leave the question open, because I'm curious about the connection of `[(ngModel)]` and native element change.

Comment: do native element change and do ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

Comment: I also thought about this, but unfortunately, it did not work. It can be checked out here on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngmodel-question-xdhp4x

Answer (score 0):

I might be late for the party but in my situation, do `this.elementRef.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))` from the directive, after set value `this.elementRef.nativeElement.value` , does update the binding `inputValue` correctly.